# Any idea how to get hold of copies of the Legends of Lone Wolf Novels?

Tags: lone-wolf, magnamund

The Lone Wolf books originally were a set of gamebooks (à la Fighting Fantasy) by Joe Dever. However, there was also a set of novels, telling the same stories as the gamebooks, by "John Grant" that I remember reading as a kid (>20 years ago). I've not seen these in print since. I'd love to find a source for the novels, electronic or paper. There is a slight issue with the difference between the UK and US releases, and I'd prefer to follow the UK editions if possible.

All I've ever managed to find is a pdf of "Eclipse of the Kai", and I'd love a reliable way to track down the rest of the books. The last official thing I read about this is that it was all tied up in a copyright wrangle with the various publishers involved.

Comment: Having re-checked amazon, I see the first 5 or so have kindle versions, but they look far from official. Only £2 each, so I may well check at least the first one out. I'd still like details on whether this is  official or not, or if there's any other source for these. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Eclipse-Legends-Lone-Wolf-ebook/dp/B0091HKDNW

Comment: Maybe [AbeBooks](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?sts=t&tn=Eclipse+of+the+Kai)? If you know the publisher or publishing year you might be able to find the UK version.

Comment: I now have the Omnibus editions, looking forward to the last 4 books being collected!

Amazon links:

[Omnibus 1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Legends-Lone-Wolf-Omnibus-1/dp/0982619707)
[Omnibus 2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Legends-Lone-Wolf-Omnibus-2/dp/1837951632)
[Omnibus 3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Legends-Lone-Wolf-Omnibus-3/dp/193705117X)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the typesetter for Dark Quest Books. The first eight books of the Legends of Lone Wolf series have been release in print in three Omnibus editions from Dark Quest, with the final four books being released in two more Omnibus editions over the next year or so.

Each of the first eight books has been released in various ebook platforms as well.

Danielle Ackley-McPhail ([www.sidhenadaire.com](http://www.sidhenadaire.com))

Comment: The first three omnibus releases were available (temporarily, at least) on Amazon UK, and I was able to pick them up.

Answer (score 7):

I work in a bookstore, so I checked up on this for you today. I remember loving those books when I was a child as well. Unfortunately, you're correct, the books are caught up in a pretty serious rights issue between the UK publisher and the US distributor, rendering it impossible to find a new copy of any of the books. Second-hand copies are available online, but you run the risk you always run with second-hand books; torn pages, coffee-stains, missing pages, etc..

Unfortunately I don't have a *Kindle* myself, so I couldn't get hold of a copy of the *Kindle* versions to look at for you, but Dark Quest Books is a perfectly legitimate publisher, albeit a small one. I have never personally dealt with them, but they don't appear to be any different from any other small-scale publishing house. You should be fine purchasing something of theirs.

Comment: I was vaguely aware of the rights issues last time I investigated (before this site was up and running :-), but yeah, UK editions of actual books, or even the omnibuses don't seem likely, notwithstanding the comments below from Dark Quest books.

Answer (score 1):

(1)   I would highly recommend www.bookfinder.com !  That website checks a huge number of online booksellers for all editions of books (or as you specify in your search).  I've ended up buying books from Amazon, Abe Books, and a few others after searches there.  I would suggest you search one title at a time, or you will get overwhelmed.  One title might give you a list of 50 search results from all the different ways that authors' names were spelled in the listings (Joe Schmoe; J. Schmoe; Schmoe; J Schmoe; J Schmoe and B. Smith; B Smith; and so on), publishers' names and variations, publishing dates, etc.  It looks like there is a new feature to combine search results, so that will make things easier.

So, for example, Goodreads says that the first book is "Flight from the Dark."  Using that new feature and using the advanced search with that title and just "Dever" as the author name, I get this [book result](https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?full=on&ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=GIUGGHczFAd3Jp,GJsbJRAO.whk_1497963026_1:1894:2123) without limiting by publisher or anything.  It looks like the cheapest copy is $6.43 from Alibris books.  You will want to revise your search by your ship-to country (in the UK?) and anything else you find important.

(2)   Check out EBay.  Sometimes with series you are able to find someone who is selling a lot comprised of most books of an old series.  This is especially true for manga, but I have seen it for old fantasy book series as well.  If your local version of EBay is not that big, try the US version EBay.com .  It looks like a lot of sellers will ship to non-US countries, and you can always message them and ask. You can also have new search results sent to your email.
Searching for your series by title and author surname (try main character name as well!): [link to Lone Wolf Dever](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=lone+wolf+series&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=lone+wolf+series+dever&_sacat=0)

[Lot of 18 books for $130](https://www.ebay.com/itm/18-Book-Lot-Of-The-Lone-Wolf-Series-RPG-by-Joe-Dever-Role-Playing/183133272669)

[Lot of 12 books for $80](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-12-Lone-Wolf-Role-Playing-Adventures-1-12-Joe-Dever/192486006762)

(3) Long-shot:  If these books were popular in your area when you were a child, try your local equivalent of Craigslist/Kijiji/Gumtree.  Look at sale and free listings, and try placing your own Wanted listing.  If smoke-free is important to you, be sure to specify that!

(4) Try your local library!  And see if your library is part of a larger network that will let you borrow/place on hold books to be shipped to your library for pickup.

(1 and 2) As you start gathering information on buying these books, you will want to put together a spreadsheet to see what is the cheapest way to buy all of them.  All individually?  One complete EBay lot?  One small EBay lot, and the rest purchased separately?  Be sure to take shipping costs into account.  I had to do this recently when buying a series for my sister.  For me, the answer was one small lot and a few individual books.

(Last)  Finally, as you wait and plan and plot, read a few online via OpenLibrary (signup required)!  You might be able to hunt down more, but here are three:
[Joe Dever at OpenLibrary](https://openlibrary.org/authors/OL760963A/Joe_Dever)

tl;dr - Try bookfinder.com, ebay.com, your local classifieds, your local library, and openlibrary.org